# Protractor element(..) returning undefined from a separate file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm writing a Protractor test and in my test.step.js file I have

```
element(by.css('...')).getText().then(function (text) {
    expect(text).to.equal('expectedText');
});
```

This works as expected and passes.

Instead I created a test.page.js file and in there put `this.field = element(by.css('...'));` and then in my step file had

```
"use strict"

module.exports = function exampleTest() {
    var TestPage = require("...");
    var testPage = new TestPage;
    ...
    test.Then(..., function (next) {
       testPage.field.getText().then(function (text) {
          expect(text).to.equal('expectedText');
       });
    });
}
```

then field is undefined. I have also tried adding getText() in the page file, but again get undefined or get told that I can't call 'then' on undefined.

In my mind, this should do exactly the same thing as the first example, but I'm far from an expert with Angular or JavaScript.

test.page.js looks like:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = (function () {
    function TestPage() {
        this.field = element(by.css('...'));
    }

    return TestPage;
});
```

Hoping someone can shine some light on why this is happening and what I should do instead to be able to put the CSS selector inside a page file for re-use.

Thanks

Comment: Have you defined it under `module.exports`? Can you add contents of test.page.js ?

Comment: Have added the contents of test.page.js. I believe that is the way to define it under module.exports.

Comment: What is `HomePage`? You should `return TestPage`. Also you need to do `var testPage = new TestPage();`

Comment: I an following an approach of grouping locators under a `PageElements'`object and re-suable methods all exported. Have provided a answer below

Comment: Have changed to TestPage. And the top of the step.js file initializes a new TestPage;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code `new TestPage;` returns the constructor `TestPage`, but it's never called.

You could return the class :

```js
function TestPage() {
    this.field = element(by.css('...'));
}

module.exports = TestPage;
```

```js
var TestPage = require("...");
var testPage = new TestPage;
testPage.field.getText().then(...
```

Or an instance of the class:

```js
function TestPage() {
    this.field = element(by.css('...'));
}

module.exports = new TestPage();
```

```js
var testPage = require("...");
testPage.field.getText().then(...
```

Comment: The first suggestion (returning the class) has worked, but I don't understand why this is different to what I had before with `module.exports = ...` and a `function TestPage() { ... }; return TestPage;` in there.

Comment: In your code, executing `new TestPage;` executes the anonymous function assigned to `module.exports`. It returns the constructor/function `TestPage` which has not been executed. So `this.field` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The way you defined re-usable element locators looks different. I am following some thing like below

Step 1: Define a .js file which should contain the Locator objects and re-usable methods

```
var Login = {

    PageElements: {
        emailInput: element(by.css('#email')),
        passwordInput: element(by.css('#password')),
        loginForm: element(by.css('#form')),
    },
    doLogin: function doLogin() {
        this.PageElements.emailInput.sendKeys('blahblah@email.com');
        this.PageElements.passwordInput.sendKeys('blahblah');
        this.PageElements.loginForm.submit();
    },
};

module.exports = Login;
```

Step 2: Call these page objects in your  test classes.

```
var LoginPage = require('../pageobjects/LoginPage.js');
it('Scenario1_Login',function(){
 LoginPage.PageElements.emailInput.sendKeys('blahblah');
});
```

More [details here](https://testautomation-aditya.com/2016/08/11/page-object-modelpom-page-object-design-pattern-in-protractor-webdriverjs-nodejs-automation-frameworks/)

Comment: your `loginPage` is an object, the question is intended when loginPage as a function is exported!  @Florent B's answer is the right way to instantiate and use exported pageObject functions!