# Trigger Kendo grid column resize using protractor

Tags: angular, protractor, kendo-grid

I am trying to automate KendoUI Grid component using protractor. Currently, I want to test column resize functionality but every time when I apply `dblclick` event to `span.k-column-resizer` element, I receive the below error:

```
TypeError: e.resizedColumns is undefined
```

Span column resizer element (complete example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enzyig?file=app/app.component.ts)):
[image]

Does anyone have experience with writing protractor tests for KendoUI Grid component to help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
TypeError: e.resizedColumns is undefined
```

Is not a Protractor related error, it is something occurs because of the following reasons:

1. Scope of variable `e.resizedColumns` defined.
2. If Promise is not resolved.
3. If the element variable has been called from some other class then that class must have its constructor like this `module.export = e`. Refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40002259/1976848)

I would suggest, edit your post and add some code snippets for more information.